# Why is multiprocessing.starmap() taking so long on a dummy function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, starmap

**Edit**

Running this in a regular `.py` file helped. Note in the original question, I was running this in a `.ipynb` file.

**Original Question**

I am incredibly new to the world of Multiprocessing in Python.

As an experiment, I wrote the following code to see the benefits of multiprocessing. Specifically, I wanted to experiment with the `starmap()` functionality.

I wrote the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    input_data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
    result = pool.starmap(add, input_data)
    print(list(result))  # Output: [3, 7, 11]
```

This code is taking a really long time to execute. It's still running and it's been about 11mins.

My desktop has 8 cores, and 16 logical processors. It's an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz.

Python version: 3.10.7

OS - Windows 10

Running it in a Python Notebook in VS Code

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you guarding with `if __name__=="__main__":`?

Comment: This executed in less than a second on my machine. Which operating system? You should get an error on Windows, but not 11 minutes run time. How to do you run it? From the command line, an IDE, clicking the file?

Comment: @JonSG No I am not guarding it with `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: On Windows, without the guard, I would expect this to infinitely recurse

Comment: @tdelaney I'm on Windows 10. I'm running it in a Python Notebook in VS Code

Comment: @JonSG that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Normally python would detect the lack of `if __name__ == "__main__":` on Windows and raise an error. Your hang must have something to do with the vscode environment. But the solution is the same.